# focus only on dialog box , not on background layout in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How can I make a dialog box in android that is always focused unless the user clicks on the button in the dialog box?

The dialog box behaves like a pop up and without closing it, it will disable on clicking on the background layout.

Comment: Can we have some Code Please !! ?

Comment: i think Alert dialogbox have by default these all properties

Comment: Yep, @imrankhan is right. Alert Dialog has by defaul the same properties.

Comment: imm.. because I use AlertDialogBuilder and inflate the custom layout. But if I tap the area outsides of the alertbox, the dialogbox disappears and back to the background layout. Thus I want to make sure user makes some input using the dialog before he returns to background layout.

Comment: @kitokid : then you can set some properties for AlertDialogBuilder like onTouch or on Backpressed to handle in your way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Sample Code`** which you can try out in your activity.

You can find Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)

```
Dialog myDialog =   new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                //Do your stuff
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                //Do your stuff
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .create();
```

Comment: Thanks. all I need is .setCancelable(false). I will accept your answer after 4 minutes.

Comment: @kitokid i did not know that what was missing in your code so i wrote whole snippet for dialog construction. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your AlertDialog get cancel if you touch outside of the dialog then just put this code to your AlertDialog to stop it cancel by outside touch.

code:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); // Where dialog is the object of your AlertDialog
```

You can also set another property to stop dismiss dialog box by BackPress key

code:

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Hope it will help you.

comment me for any query.

Enjoy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create your own dialog box,

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DialogBoxActivity.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
                    dialog.setTitle("This is dialog box");
                    dialog.setCancelable(true);


                    //set up text
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                    text.setText("Are you sure you want to exit");



                    //set up button
                    Button yes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yes);
                    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                    @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    Button no = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.no);
                    no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
```

and also define its layout as, maindialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >




    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="192dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView01" >

 <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:text="  Yes  " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yes"
        android:text="  No   " />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It will create a custom layout for the dialog box and could only be dismissed on button click.